# scipy.signal.lsim and scipy.signal.step output and use-case

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

The output of scipy.signal.step and scipy.signal.lsim are not what I'd like them to be, so I must be using them wrong. The output of lsim is actually quite close, but the amplitude is attenuated by many orders of magnitude. Is my problem that a linear system can't be non-zero for zero input? My initial condition is 1.65V (I'm modeling an op amp circuit), and in real life the input is 1.65V for a long time >> time constant of the circuit, before the step occurs.

I've plotted all waveforms and zoomed in on the output of lsim by itself, to see that has a roughly accurate shape.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy import signal

time = np.linspace(0,1e-3, num=100)
fc = 2e3
tau = 1/(2*np.pi*fc)
gain = .7
step_amplitude=.4
initial = 1.65
input_step = [1.65 for i in range(20)] + [2 for i in range(80)]

ideal_ckt = signal.ZerosPolesGain([],[-3e3*2*np.pi],[gain])
t, ideal_step = signal.step(ideal_ckt, X0=[1.65],T= time)
t, output, x = signal.lsim(ideal_ckt, input_step, T=time)

should_be = step_amplitude*gain*(1-np.exp(-(time)/tau)) + initial
should_be[20:] = should_be[0:80]
should_be[0:20] = 1.65

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(time, input_step, label='input')
ax.plot(t, output, label='lsim')
ax.plot(time, ideal_step, label='signal.step')
ax.plot(time, should_be, label='should_be')
ax.set_xlabel('time')
ax.set_ylabel('Voltage')
ax.legend()
fig.show()
```

I expect to see a nice RC-like, first order exponential rise to the steady state value of initial value + input step amplitude * gain.  I expect the curves of `should_be`, `ideal_step`, and `output` to all look the same. Why don't they?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system should be defined as:

```
ideal_ckt = signal.ZerosPolesGain([],[-p1*1],[gain*p1])
```

Because of the way the documentation describes the form. This explains the large attentuation:
1/(s/p+1) is the normalized form. But the form of the scipy code is 1/(s+p). To get from the first form to the second form you end up with p/(s+p)